# MySQL Search optimisation for better performance

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have an array with a list of keywords,

`$arr = array('london','england','football',...);`

The array could have N<sup>th</sup> keywords.

I need to use this on a sql query but i dont want to do too many repetitions like this.

`select * from t1 where title LIKE('%$arr[0]%') OR title LIKE('%$arr[1]%') [...]`

just need a better solution as each keyword filters out the records.

thnx

Comment: Look at MySQL's full text search ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to create a lookup table that is populated with the rowid and keywordid whenever a row is created or changed.

Then you can skip all the LIKE and get much more performance.

A trigger on insert and update should work but it will cost a little more performance on insert and update.

You would just use

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM lookup WHERE keywordid IN ())
```

And if the keywords are many you could use a sub query more to get the keyword id's or if fewer use a cached lookup structure directly in code, dictionary or likewise.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/sql/tutorial_mysql_in_and_between.php3

Comment: But this only works if title is exactly the keyword, not if the title contains the keywords as the given example looks for with `LIKE '%nnn%'`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure whether you wanted to optimize the actual query itself or the means to insert keywords into the query.
If it's the latter, then what comes to mind quickly is:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE title";

foreach($arr as $keyword)
{
    $stack[] = " LIKE '%$keyword%' ";
}

$query .= implode(' OR title ', $stack);
```

If you want to avoid full table scans based on keywords, that requires a different topic in itself with more explanation at your end.

Comment: I preferred a mysql query rather than php, as php loops are easy :) just wanted it to perform better on mysql :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the kind *(and amount)* of searches you'll be doing, you might need to consider using something else than pure-MySQL for that.

MySQL by itself is not quite well-suited when it comes to fulltext search :

- Using `like '%...%'` will result in bad performances *(scanning all the lines of your table)*
- Using a `FULLTEXT` index means using MyISAM as storage engine.

If you need to do a lot of searches, it might become more interesting to invest in a solution dedicated to indexing/searching through text, like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), or [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/).

Comment: well im trying to lookup a db just like tag clouds the more keywords you enter the more it narrows down your search e.g. searching for a car, make, colour, and all the other options if that makes sense like a filtering system